# Is there an 'offline' version of Google calendar for Android?

Tags: calendar, offline, google-calendar

For the PC there is a plugin for the google calendar so that edits to the calendar can be made offline. On my Android 2.1 there does not seem such an option.

I am using the calendar though the browser and not an app. On the app market place I cannot find the app so I am using the browser..

Comment: Am I missing something here? The native Google Calendar app has offline editing capability.

Comment: Because phones often don't have connectivity, by and large apps are made to work "offline". The exception, of course, are apps that are just wrappers around a browser for a web app. I use my Calendar app without connectivity all of the time. There's no concept of an "offline" calendar option because it's baked into the app. Are you perhaps accessing the calendar via the browser?

Comment: @Al Everett yes... I worded it wrong, but I am using the calendar though the browser and not an app. On the app market place I cannot find the app so I am using the browser.

Comment: Please update your question with this information, and included what device you're using. No calendar app installed with the OS? It doesn't look like it's one of the apps that Google has updated, but there are [plenty of alternatives](https://market.android.com/search?q=calendar&so=1&c=apps). All that said, the built-in Android browser doesn't support any sort of extensions like the browser on your desktop does. What you're asking for doesn't exist. Use an app.

Comment: much related IMHO: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21246/how-can-i-search-the-google-calendar-from-the-android-phone?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in several comments, the Calendar app *is* the way to interact with your calendar offline.

If you're interacting with the calendar via the browser, you need to be connected. The Android browser doesn't support any sort of "plug-in".

Answer (score 1):

If you sync the Google account used with the calendar to the phone, the calendars can be synced too and viewed/edited offline with your phones' Calendar app.