# How can I search the Google Calendar from the Android phone?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I would have thought that Calendars would be searchable, but opening up the Calendar, and clicking on the search button searches websites via Google web search, but does not search my Calendar.

This is on a Motorola Photon 4G Android version 2.3.4 (not rooted).

How do I do it on the phone (it is possible from a desktop browser).

I have installed the Google Search app, and tried to add Calendar to the list of applications it would search, but there is no entry for Calendar.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky -- on spiffy shiny brand-spanking-new Android 4.0.4, the search button does _nothing_.

Answer (score 3):

On Ice Cream Sandwich, the search button is in the "..." menu:

[image]

Comment: offby1's comment on my main post says the above does nothing.  Are you able to use that search feature to find your own calendar entries from your phone? And if so, what is the make and model of your phone and specific Android version?

Comment: @bgoodr: the search works perfectly, I think offby1's comment was referring to that in many handset with Android 4.0, like in my Galaxy Nexus, there is no dedicated search button as in previous versions.

Comment: @bgoodr: offby1 could also be referring to older Android handsets like Nexus S or Galaxy S that gets updated to Android 4, it's certainly plausible that some of those handsets have a poorly tested upgrade that broke the hardware search button, but that would probably be the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'm out of luck on this handset.  I'm puzzled by Google has dragged their feet on something as basic as searching Calendar on the Android for versions of Android < 4.  I mean, can it be _that_ hard, really?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have to launch the **Calendar** app, then you can open the Options menu and choose **Search**.  Then you can search your Calendar.  If you've got a Search hard key, you should be able to press that as well once you're in the app.

Note that on Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich, the Search is going to be in the overflow menu.

I looked and there's no Search Provider for Calendar for some reason, which is necessary if you're going to be able to search that app's data from the main search box on the home screen.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that works for you on your phone, but it does not on mine. First, clicking on the **menu** button shows **Settings**, and not **Options**. Second, when **Settings** is viewed, I see no entry for **Search** at all.  I'm conclude that there is no single "Calendar app" that has the same look and feel across all Android phones.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I couldn't make the following method work on my Android 4.2!**

At least nowadays it limits offline search for a few weeks. If you want more, try something like [this](http://androidforums.com/asus-eee-pad-transformer/384425-solved-google-calendar-history-more-than-month.html#post3010948)...

But first, if you have ***auto sync*** enabled, ***disable it*** for as long as needed to finish all steps:

1. On the device, set the date back to January of 2000 or some old date.
2. Go to *Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All*
3. Find "Calendar Storage" and hit "Clear Data"
4. Go to *Accounts & Sync* and choose your google account
5. Hit the Sync button in upper right corner. Let it finish
6. Now at this point reset your date back to the actual date
7. Perform the Sync again

It will take longer this time depending on how much calendar data needs to be transferred.